# Drupal 2-phase submission

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, submission

Using Drupal 6 I'm looking for a 2-phase submission:

1. User fills form and push "Send"
2. Form is visualized as read-only with button "Back" and "Confirm"

Is there a module for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CTools module](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) is probably the closest, it has a helper API to create multistep forms. There's a [tutorial here](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/multi-step-forms-using-form-api-and-ctools).

Other than that you would need to create you own [multistep form](http://www.ferolen.com/blog/how-to-create-multistep-form-in-drupal-6-tutorial/)